# What's the opposite of "trauma"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Words like *healing* and *relief* often come up, but I don't think they really capture the intensity of a positive experience to the same degree as "trauma" captures a negative experience.

For example:

> Were you traumatised by a horror movie as a child?
>   <sup>[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2012/oct/25/traumatised-horror-movie-child)</sup>

What would be its opposite?

Comment: Not everything has an opposite. Is pleasure the opposite of pain, or is no pain the opposite of pain?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I've added the [single-word-requests] tag. Could you have a look at [the advice on SWR questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) -- this question needs a better definition of what you're looking for, as @MrShiny indicates. A question can be reactivated from on-hold.